# How to get currently selected text from Thunderbird Message Composer

Tags: javascript, thunderbird-addon

In Thunderbird's message composer, I need to use javascript to see if the user has selected any text, and optionally get that selected text.

I tried this:

```
var thisselection = window.getSelection();
alert("selection = " + thisselection.toString() );
```

But even if text is selected, it says nothing is selected.  I am sure I don't understand what is going on.  [I was reading from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection).

I've also tried:

```
var editor = gMsgCompose.editor; 
var thisselection = editor.getSelection.toString();
```

but then I get an error saying `getSelection` is not a function to be used with `editor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found it:

```
var thisselection = document.commandDispatcher.focusedWindow.getSelection();
var thistext = thisselection.toString();
alert(thistext);
```

Comment: Your answer saved my day!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (not so magic as `commandDispatcher`):

```
var editor = document.getElementById("content-frame");
var edocument = editor.contentDocument;
var sel = edocument.getSelection();
```